# Is default Swing look and feel the same on all platforms?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I want to know if there will be font color, scrollbar or rounded corner changes when switching Java versions or platforms.

We are customizing with background images and stuff so it really does not look like any native platform. If we were not using our own so-called-look-and-feel, we would use the native-look-alike look and feel and this question would not arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to find this on your own

1) try it.
2) type it on the internet

answer
to the best of my knowledge yes.
I have a mac and a windows and they all look the same except for the top menue bar which is grey on my mac and blue on my windows.
JFrame frame = new JFrame(""); this is the only part that looks different

Comment: Have tried it already, and have done some searching, but did not find what I was looking for with my search terms. I already suspected the answer was yes, but I posted this question to be sure.